# how can I test that a value is getting updated in the ngrx store?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a component with a function that dispatches an event that updates the user's preferences in the store:

```
  updatePreferences(prefs) {
    this.store.dispatch(patchCurrentUserPreferences({ preferences: prefs }));
  }
```

I am trying to write a test that will actually prove that this works.

The component has an observable `preferences$` property, and in the real world, if I do:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.preferences$.subscribe((preferences) => {
    console.log('in real world', preferences);
  });
}
```

then I see that the user's preferences are in fact properly getting updated, so everything IS working...  However, when I subscribe to the `preferences$` observable in the test world, I only see it get called when the mock store is being setup with the initial state:

```
provideMockStore({
  initialState: {
    [currentUserFeatureKey]: {
       user: { preferences: { wut: 'lol'} },
    },
  },
})
```

So for example, with this test, I am only seeing the logging happen one time, when the component is instantiated and the initial state is triggering the callback...

```
it('updates the user preferences', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.preferences$.subscribe((prefs) => {
    console.log('in test world', prefs);
  });
  component.updatePreferences({ some_prop: 'some val' });
  flushMicrotasks();
}));
```

I see:

```
LOG: 'in real world', Object{wut: 'lol'}
LOG: 'in test world', Object{wut: 'lol'}
```

So it seems that the dispatch call is not doing anything-- or that action is stuck in a queue that is not getting invoked?  I thought if that's the case, `flushMicrotasks` or `tick(1000)` would do the job, but it's not...

Comment: Why not simply inject Store in your test and call `updatePreferences`? Something like:
`const store = TestBed.inject(Store)`;
`component. updatePreferences()`
`do your stuff here...`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on how to test applications using NgRx, maybe it helps https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project.

The reason why the selector isn't firing is because you're using the mockstore.
To test the reducer you have two options:

- write a unit test on the component with mockstore, and write reducer tests
- write integration test on the component, this requires you to use the "real" store, this way the selector will receive updates